# Angular ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically

Tags: angular

After adding dynamic template loading according to device type, I get the following error when executing build command. But it works fine when running using `ng server`

Error I got when using build command (`ng build --prod --build-optimizer --base-href=.`
):

```
ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 11:12 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol ɵ0 in /home/private/3/nie-frontend/src/app/smiley-feedback/smiley-feedback.component.ts, resolving symbol SmileyFeedbackComponent in /home/private/3/nie-frontend/src/app/smiley-feedback/smiley-feedback.component.ts, resolving symbol SmileyFeedbackComponent in /home/private/3/nie-frontend/src/app/smiley-feedback/smiley-feedback.component.ts, resolving symbol SmileyFeedbackComponent in /home/private/3/nie-frontend/src/app/smiley-feedback/smiley-feedback.component.ts
```

Following is my `component` code

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { GlobalVariableService } from '../shared/services/global-variable.service';
import { FeedbackService } from '../shared/services/feedback.service';

import { AgtContentService } from '../shared/services/agt-content.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-smiley-feedback',
  template:function(){
    if(SmileyFeedbackComponent.detectmob()) {

      return require("./smiley-feedback.component.mobile.html");
    }
    else
    {
      return require("./smiley-feedback.component.html");
    }
  }(),
  styleUrls: ['./smiley-feedback.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class SmileyFeedbackComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private globalVariable: GlobalVariableService, private router: Router, private feedback: FeedbackService,
              private agtContentService: AgtContentService) {

    // this.agtContentService.smileys = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  static detectmob() {
    if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
    ){
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  onClickSmiley(smiley): void {
    if (smiley.rating == "EXTREMELY_DISSATISFIED" || smiley.rating == "DISSATISFIED" ) {
      this.router.navigate(['feedback']);
    }
    else {
      this.router.navigate(['thank-you'])
    }

    this.feedback.rating = smiley.rating;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
template:function(){
   if(SmileyFeedbackComponent.detectmob()) {

     return require("./smiley-feedback.component.mobile.html");
   }
   else
   {
     return require("./smiley-feedback.component.html");
   }
}()
```

can not be statically resolved. During AOT, because the compiler tries to determine the value statically, it throws an error for any code that might modify the values that are referenced.

As stated in the exception you can use an export function such as:

```
// in component decorator use
template: determineView()

// determine view
export function determineView() {

  if (SmileyFeedbackComponent.detectmob()) {
    return require("./smiley-feedback.component.mobile.html");
  }
  else
  {
    return require("./smiley-feedback.component.html");
  }
}
```

Since you have not provided a plunkr I can not verify that this works in this case. 
But also try the following: 
Dont use "template" and require the file, rather use templateUrl and return the relative path to the file as a string, such as:

```
// in component decorator use
templateUrl: determineView()

// determine view
export function determineView() {

  if (SmileyFeedbackComponent.detectmob()) {
    return './smiley-feedback.component.mobile.html';
  }
  else
  {
    return './smiley-feedback.component.html';
  }
}
```

Comment: this gives an error saying `ERROR in src/app/smiley-feedback/smiley-feedback.component.ts(9,1): error TS1206: Decorators are not valid here.`

Comment: It is really difficult to help debug with just this message. Can you please provid a working example (e.g. a plunkr) with your code?